# Microsoft Teams search messaging extension with configurable Authentication servers

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to create Microsoft Teams search messaging extension with OAuth.

The problem is, our customers host their servers, and because of that, they have different Authentication servers.

For example there is 2 company, Company1 and Company2, and they have 2 servers, company1.com and company2.com, and they have 2 Authentication server (company1.com/auth and company2/auth).
And if a user from Company1 wants to use the messaging extension, the user wants to log in with the company1.com/auth Authentication server.

Is there a solution (what works with 1000+ customer), where every customer can use their own Authentication server to log in? (Without manipulation OAuth Connection Settings in the Bot Channel Registration)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the scenario, and I'm also not an auth expert, but perhaps this will help: You could register multiple OAuth connection entries with the bot, inside the Azure portal (i.e. one for Company 1 and one for Company 2). Next, inside your bot, when the message extension is invoked, it passes along the tenant id of the user who invoked it, and you could use this to perform a lookup against which OAuth connection to use.

Comment: Yes, that was I tried first, but that doesn't scale well, that's why I doesn't wanted to manipulate the OAuth Connection Settings. But my question was misleading a little, so I added the 1000+ customer line to it. So I search for a solution where I doesn't need to know about the customer servers.

Comment: What kind of authentication are you talking about then in this case? Perhaps explain about what all these 'authentication servers' are? Are the customers NOT using Azure AD for auth?

Comment: No, they are not using Azure AD, all servers are an independent OAuth server (own user database, same as the Github or Google).

So currently the workflow is this: 
The user set the server/tenant => user log in (through Azure Oauth Connection Settings) => Azure get Auth code => Azure exchange it for access token => Azure managing the token

But we don't want hard-coded OAuth settings, because if a new customer comes, we have to add it to the list. So I am searching for a solution, what can work without register any services in OAuth Connection Settings.